Python custom decarotor multiple implementation for single function
I am creating multiple custom decorators in python
def make_bold(func):
    def core(*args, **kwargs):
        func(*args, **kwargs)
        print(f"running {func.__name__} for bold")
    return core

def make_italic(func):
    def core(*args, **kwargs):
        func(*args, **kwargs)
        print(f"running {func.__name__} for italic")
    return core

and applying two decorators to single fucntion.
@make_bold
@make_italic
def say():
   return "Hello"

when I run sah function
print(say())

prints
running say for italic
running core for bold

but it should be:
running say for italic
running say for bold

why does not get same decorated name? How can I fix it?
